# size of barcode in pspicture

Tags: standalone, pst-barcode

I´m on a way to create a barcode with `pst-barcode`. How can I get a suitable pspicture environment in a standalone class? In the following example the top and right borders are too big.

```
% run with XeLaTeX => PDF
\documentclass[border = 1pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(1in, 1in)
    \psbarcode{http://www.dante.de}{}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the default size of a qrcode is

```
\begin{pspicture}(50bp,50bp) 
  \psbarcode{http://www.dante.de}{}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
```

which can be increased or decreased by setting the optional arguments

Answer (score 1):

OMG!

```
% run with XeLaTeX => PDF
\documentclass[border = 1pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(1in, 1in)
    \psbarcode{http://www.dante.de}{width=1.0 height=1.0}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it depends to the the size you really want to create